# Set.include? for custom objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a class roughly like this:

```
class C
    attr_accessor :board # board is a multidimensional array (represents a matrix)

    def initialize
        @board = ... # initialize board
    end   

    def ==(other)
        @board == other.board
    end
end
```

Still, when I do:

```
s = Set.new
s.add(C.new)
s.include?(C.new) # => false
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Set` uses `eql?` and `hash`, not `==`, to test two objects for equality.  See, for example, [this documentation of Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html): "The equality of each couple of elements is determined according to Object#eql? and Object#hash, since Set uses Hash as storage."

If you want two different `C` objects to be the same for set membership, you'll have to override those two methods.

```
class C
  attr_accessor :board 

  def initialize
    @board = 12
  end

  def eql?(other)
    @board == other.board
  end

   def hash
    @board.hash
  end
end

s = Set.new
s.add C.new
s.include? C.new   # => true
```

Comment: I upvoted, but accepted steenslag's answer since it shows `eql?` isn't called by Hash, which is interesting to me. Thank you anyway.

Comment: `eql?` *is* called by `Hash` if two elements have the same `hash` value. That's just how hashes work: because of the Pigeonhole Principle, there are an infinite number of objects which have the same `hash` value but aren't actually equal. Therefore, you can use `hash` to *quickly* determine that two objects are definitely *not* equal, but if you want to know whether they are definitely *equal*, you need to check every object with the same `hash` value using `eql?`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something below :

```
require 'set'
class C
  attr_accessor :board 

  def initialize
    @board = 12
  end

  def ==(other)
    @board == other.board
  end
end
s = Set.new
c = C.new
s.add(c)
s.include? c # => true
```

The reason below will not work:

```
s.add(C.new)
s.include?(C.new) # => false
```

Using `C.new` you create 2 different objects. If you do run `C.new` thrice then you will get 3 different objects:

```
C.new.object_id # => 74070710
C.new.object_id # => 74070360
C.new.object_id # => 74070030
```

***Summary*** : The instance of C you added to `s`,using `Set#add` and the instance of C you are checking using `Set#include?` are 2 different objects. So the result you got is more obvious.

Comment: I downvoted since this doesn't answer my question. I know that asking for the inclusion of the *same object* would return true, I care about adding two different object which share the same structure. Anyway, as the other answers say, the key is using `hash`.

Comment: @whatyouhide You down-vote me it is no problem for me.. But only problem is You are doing some mistakes to understand the difference between your class `C` and class `Set`. Follow this [**conversion**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38656/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-brabertaser1992),hope you will understand what the wrong is going on inside you. The answer you accepted is same as me. Why are you thinking `Set#include?` will compare the object using the method of `C#==`. Just for clarity check the implementation of `Set#add` and `Set#include?`.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your comment, anyway read the comment by Jorg M Mittag: I needed a set to consider two objects with different IDs but same characteristics as the same object. You told me that adding two different objects (with a different ID specifically) to a Set caused the set to consider them as different objects, which I knew already.

Comment: @whatyouhide So you didn't told that in your post. And your code doesn't show the same.In such a case no one can give you the answer as per your need. The answer you accepted is the same What I did also. You still didn't understand the basic mistake that you are thinking.

Comment: Yeah ok, whatever. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I still think this answer is useless in order to understand the behavior of Set. You mention the object ID ad the reason why this objects are different to the eyes of a set, but it's not the (only) reason. The reason why sets behave this way is because different *custom* objects give different hashes, regardless of the object id. Array, instead, returns the same hash for arrays with the same content even if their ID is different.

Comment: @whatyouhide You need to take time to understand the concept..I am sure,you will get the things what I meant to say,once you will be grown up with Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

```
class C
    attr_accessor :board # board is a multidimensional array (represents a matrix)

    def initialize
        board = [[1],[2]] # initialize board
        p @board #=> nil !!

    end 
    def ==(other)
        @board == other.board
    end

    def eql?(other) # not used
        puts "eql? called"
        @board == other.board
    end
    def ==(other) # not used
        puts "== called"
        @board == other.board
    end

    def hash
      puts "hash called"
      board.hash
    end
end
require 'set'
s = Set.new
s.add(c = C.new)
p s.include?(c)
```

Set uses a Hash as storage underneath. Output:

```
nil
hash called
hash called
true
```

Comment: Why is method `==(other)` defined twice in this example?